# Import from Adjacent Script Tag with ES6 Modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, script-tag, html-imports

With ES6 modules, is there a current method, or one in the pipeline, to `import` a module from a `<script>` tag already on the page? For example, if I have 2 `<script>` tags,

```
<script id="a">
    export const a = 'a';
</script>
<script id="b">
    import a from ?;
    console.log(a);
</script>
```

what do I put into the `import` statement in the second `<script>` tag, in place of the question mark?

The `id` attribute is for identification purposes, as, obviously, there needs to be some way to identify the `<script>` tag you need. It could be done with classes or any other way, but IDs must be unique (though many browsers just use the last tag with an `id`), so I thought it was a good way to ensure you have the correct tag. It could also be done by getting the `<script>` tag by position in the document: for example, here you are getting the second script tag, so perhaps you could do something like

```
import a from window.scripts[1];
```

One more thing: if this could work across HTML imports, that would be great, too. My original purpose was to re-use React components across different pages of a site, where they may not be able to be imported with relative paths, and, at least with Webpack, absolute paths are not always relative to the server's root: sometimes they are relative to the computer's root, or at least the webserver's root.

**How do I import values directly from another `<script>` tag on the page?**

Comment: Based on a read of [the `script` section of the WHAT-WG HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element), which is as close to a spec for modules in the browser as we currently have, I think the answer is: No, there's no way to do that. I can't answer the pipeline question because it's always possible that something is hidden away in some obscure discussion area the vendors use.

Comment: But more to the point, I don't see how it solves the problem you describe. Just like any other linked resource, you need to provide the correct relative path to the resource. You'd have to do that even if the resources were embedded in HTML files. If you're having trouble using relative paths reliably in Webpack, I suggest nailing down how you do that (since it's not chaotic), rather than looking for baroque solutions like this.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. You are right, I always try to find the clever solution before the smart solution. Here, I wanted the HTML import to be the component, using React. Unfortunately, React doesn't like you messing around with the DOM behind its back, but I will have to find other ways around this. Thanks again.

Comment: I always wondered anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question and if my reputation was higher I probably would have added this as a comment...

The unsatisfactory way I hade to use in a similar case was to place every variable from the first module on the window

[I read something about using eval() but haven't tried to test it. as I detest the eval function.]

@T.J. Crowder: I have the following structure

```
/app
  /modules
    main.js
    other.js
    feature.js
/customer-page1
  index.html
 /data
    data.js
/page2
    index.html
 /data
    data.js
/Page3
    index.html
 /data
    data.js
```

It's a kind of complicated quiz-app. We add new features and the customers update there index.html.

Questions are in the HTML an the data/data.js contain complex structured data.
We want/need modules as we load the feature.js dynamically.

The data.js sometimes needs to have evaluation function in addition to the raw data, which can differ from client to client, so a pure JSON isn't cutting it, and we still would have the path-problem, as main.js has to work on all pages
and is referenced as

```
<script type='module' src="/app/modules/main.js"></script>
```

while data is easily referenced as

```
<script type='module' src="data/data.js"></script>
```

from index.html

As we work with pure (no framework) Typescript we also need the modules is data  for type-checking to see definitions in /app...

I would be very happy to find a more elegant solution though.